# Loading an image inside a bottom navigation bar item icon using an URL

Tags: java, android, android-glide, bottom-navigation-bar

I'm trying to load a profile image using the firebase storage url inside an item's icon of a bottom navigation bar, here's my code:

```
 Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).asBitmap().load(profilePicUrl)
    .into(new CustomTarget<Bitmap>() {

        @Override
        public void onResourceReady(@NonNull Bitmap resource, @Nullable Transition<? super Bitmap> transition) {
            Drawable profileImage = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), resource);
            bottomNav.getMenu().getItem(4).setIcon(profileImage);
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadCleared(@Nullable Drawable placeholder) {

        }
    });
```

The `profilePicUrl` does work, I already use it to for another image view. However when I run the app, the dimensions of the icon changes corresponding to the picture that I'm trying to load but there's no image inside, [here's how it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ni0aE.jpg).

Comment: Have you tried to reduce the size of the image?

Comment: @AlexMamo that is not the issue. Check my answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Menus do not support coloured images**

You can not use a coloured image in these places and a bit more also:

1. In bottom navigation
2. In navigation drawer
3. In popup menu
4. etc...

Basically which ever view uses a menu file for its resource, cannot have a coloured image. That is why you don't see it. To test it yourself, take a colourful image in your drawable and set it as an icon for the bottom navigation. You notice that it comes the same way. This proves it

### Edits

---

1. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57861254/17133283) post gives some info on how to do it
2. You can do it this way:

   ```
   mBottomNav.setItemIconTintList(null);
   ```

Comment: Oh yes, you're right I tried to change the color of the icon and I'm still seeing a grey color. But then again how do the other apps achieve this effect? do you have any suggestions please?

Comment: Yes I tried it and it works exactly as intended, thank you very much!